# Computing a certain partial derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm working through [this PDE textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) and am trying to understand where I'm going wrong in reproducing a computation of a second partial derivative $u_{x_i x_i}$ in the text (for reference, $\S$2.2.1.a, p.21).

We start with $u(x) = v(r)$, where $r(x) = \|x\|_2 = (x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^{-1/2}$, then compute 
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^{-1/2} 2x_i = \frac{x_i}{r}$$ Fine, so far so good. The first derivative $u_{x_i}$ follows easily: 
$$u_{x_i} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} = u_r \frac{x_i}{r} = v'(r)\frac{x_i}{r}$$
The trouble (for me) comes in computing the second derivative. The text states 
$$u_{x_i x_i} = v''(r)\frac{x_i^2}{r^2} + v'(r)\left(\frac{1}{r}- \frac{x_i^2}{r^3}\right)$$

When I work through it myself, I find
\begin{align*}
u_{x_i x_i} = \frac{\partial u_{x_i}}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[ v'(r)\frac{x_i}{r}\right]\cdot\frac{x_i}{r} \\
&= \left( v''(r)\frac{x_i}{r} + v'(r)\left(-\frac{x_i}{r^2}\right)\right)\frac{x_i}{r} \\
&= v''(r)\frac{x_i^2}{r^2} - v'(r)\frac{x_i^2}{r^3}
\end{align*}

It seems I must be missing (or forgetting) something. In order to arrive  at the result in the text, it would appear that we should have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[ \frac{x_i}{r} \right] = \frac{1}{x_i}- \frac{x_i}{r^2},$$ but why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by differentiating the product,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( \frac{v'(r)}{r} \cdot x_i \right) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( \frac{v'(r)}{r} \right) \cdot x_i + 
\frac{v'(r)}{r} \cdot 1=
\dots,
$$
*then* use the chain rule. What you forgot is that $x_i$ depends on $r$.

Comment: I thought $r$ depended on $x_i$, not the other way around.

Comment: Think of it as a change from Cartesian coordinates $x_i$ to polar coordinates ($r$ and some angle variables). Viewing this change of variables in the opposite direction shows that all the $x_i$ depend on $r$ and on the angles. Taking the partial derivative $\partial/\partial r$ means varying $r$ and keeping the angles fixed, and this will change all the $x_i$.

Comment: So whenever we have a situation where the variables are mutually dependent (like a change of coordinates), taking a partial derivative w/r/t one variable will involve the others as well. Is this thinking correct?

Comment: Yes. Actually I see now that you also made another mistake which was more subtle. After "When I work through it myself, I find", you are applying a rule which works for a function depending only on $r$ (but not on the angles) to the function $u_{x_i}$ which does *not* only depend on $r$ but also on $x_i$ and hence implicitly on the angles. In this situation you would need to use the general chain rule with one term for $r$ and one term for each angle variable (unless you do as in my answer and avoid this problem!).

Comment: OK, I think that clears it up for me.